# MySQL - UPDATE in batches using WHILE DO

Tags: mysql

Can someone give me pointers on what I'm doing wrong here?

I keep getting `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near...`

I'm trying to run an UPDATE command in small batches to prevent the table from being blocked (while running through 10 million records).

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION batch_update()
BEGIN
  SET processed = 0;
  SET eachbatch = 1000;

  WHILE processed < 1000000 DO          
      UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `active` = 0 LIMIT eachbatch;

       -- Finish when no rows remaining
      IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 THEN LEAVE;
      END IF;

      -- No infinite loop, thanks
      SET processed = processed + eachbatch;
  END WHILE;
END //

DELIMITER ;

CALL batch_update();
```

**Edit:** For anyone that needs a pointer, I got it working like this:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS process_batch_rows;   

DELIMITER //    
CREATE FUNCTION process_batch_rows() RETURNS VARCHAR(10) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE processed INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE eachbatch INT DEFAULT 1000;

  my_loop: WHILE processed < 1000000
  DO
    UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `active` = 0 LIMIT eachbatch;

    IF ROW_COUNT() < 1 THEN
        LEAVE my_loop;
    END IF;

    SET processed = processed + eachbatch;
  END WHILE my_loop;    

  RETURN "Done";
END //    
DELIMITER ;

SELECT process_batch_rows();
```

Comment: call a function??

Comment: Yeah, that is one of the things I did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This one I have added comments wherever needed =>

```
DELIMITER //

-- You must specify return type

CREATE FUNCTION batch_update() RETURNS VARCHAR(10) DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN

    -- you must declare variables

    DECLARE processed int(10);

    DECLARE eachbatch int(10);

    SET processed = 0;

    SET eachbatch = 1000;

    -- needed my loop here so it can be used in leave

    myloop: WHILE processed < 1000000 DO          

        UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `active` = 0 LIMIT eachbatch;

        -- Finish when no rows remaining

        IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 

        THEN 

            LEAVE myloop;

        END IF;

        -- No infinite loop, thanks

        SET processed = processed + eachbatch;

    END WHILE;

    return 'Done';

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me identify some of the issues I was having.